# Why does Bochs loop indefinitely while waiting for response from floppy disk

Tags: bochs

I'm writing an **32 bits** experimental OS under **MacOSX catalina10.15.6**, and I try to read the floppy by using port *0x1F0*~*0x1F7* to load my kernel.But there are some bugs, so I wan't to debug with **Bochs**。But every time I step into the lable `.wait`，the **bochs** will never jump out, it looped endless.How do I get **Bochs** to **read the floppy and return from this function `read_disk32_lba`**?

this is my `.bochsrc`:

```
floppya: 1_44=os-image, status=inserted
boot: a
log: log.txt
```

and this is the function to read disk in read.asm(using **nasm**):

```
;read a sector in LBA mode
;@param ds:edi buffer address
;       ebx    the sector index
;       
read_disk32_lba: 
    mov al, 1
    mov dx, 0x1F2
    out dx, al   ;read one sector

    ;write the sector index to ports
    mov dx, 0x1F3
    mov al, bl
    out dx, al

    inc dx      ;0x1F4
    mov al, bh
    out dx, al

    inc dx      ;0x1F5
    shr ebx, 16
    mov al, bl
    out dx, al

    inc dx          ;0x1F6
    mov al, bh
    or al, 0xE0     ;use LBA mode to read
    out dx, al

    mov al, 0x20
    mov dx, 0x1F7
    out dx, al       ;ask for read

    ;wait for a response from the disk
    .waits:
        in al, dx
        mov ah, al
        and ah, 0x01
        cmp ah, 0x01
        jz .error
        and al, 0x88
        cmp al, 0x08
        jnz .waits

    ;write dataes to buffer
    mov dx, 0x1F0
    mov ecx, 256
    .read: 
        in ax, dx
        mov [edi], ax
        add edi, 2
        loop .read
    jmp .end

    ;error handling
    .error:
        mov esi, READ_ERROR
        call print_string32
        hlt
    .end:
    ret

READ_ERROR: db 'Kernel read error', 0
```

and I compiled the asm file by:

```
nasm read.asm -f bin -o read.o
```